# Jquery load local picture into dialog open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-ui

Good afternoon stackoverflow community, i'm having an problem in load local jpeg into dialog open,
    with the code below will always append the same table information 
    and reopen it on the dialog, i might done something wrong.

```
Local file path: D:/web/pic/123.jpg
```

Please provide some help here, thank you.

Below is my code:

### Html part:

Tag id will reference to the jquery code

```
<div id="dialog" title="picture">
   <span><img  src="/pic/123.jpg"/></span>   //src get local file picture
</div>
```

### Jquery part:

```
        $('#info').click(function() {     
             $('#dialog').append('<img   // get local file 
             src="pic/123.jpg"/><br/>').append($(this).html());

              $("#dialog").dialog("open");    //dialog open start here
        $('#dialog').dialog({
                 resizable:false,
                 buttons: {
                     "Close": function()      //button on pop out dialog
                     {
                         $(this).dialog('close');
                         choice(true);
                     },
                     "Cancel Close": function() //button on pop out dialog
                     {
                         $(this).dialog('close');
                         choice(false);
                     }
                 }
             });
 });
```

From the code above change to src="file///web/pic/123.jpg"
   Only able to get data from the compiler, using web browser chrome, ie or etc.
   Won't get any picture why?

[image]

Comment: question is unclear(atleast to me) .. what is actual problem? is image not displaying in the browser? or any other?

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Image doesn't display on browser while i have change src="file///D:/web/pic/123.jpg
But it does show while using compiler to build entire web project

Comment: try this `../pic/123.jpg` in the image path. assuming that `pic` is a folder in your application.

Comment: @Kiranramchandran i have try ../pic/123.jsp still the same, it seen like the browser don't understand how to get it, if copy the file///D:/web/pic/123.jpg paste it directly to the browser it will appear

Comment: does you developer console show any error?

Comment: @Kiranramchandran no i'm using eclipse, it don't appear any error, i also check through develop mode of chrome and internet explorer the src="file///D:/web/pic/123.jpg is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184509/discussion-between-kiranramchandran-and-victor).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load local pictures on a web application it is considered unsafe.
You should put your images on your web host along with other web resources.

If you make a simple html and you run it locally it will work, but this is the only case.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to put all the images and files inside application/server relative path only instead of local storage.
Put all the images and files inside resource folder and from that you can load easily any image by path and file name.

Comment: @Sandy i have try to put it in the server (tomcat) while jsp is launching by eclipse, but still the same, if using the debug mode browser within eclipse the picture can be view.

Comment: can you share your project structure?